# Question related to damping, quality factor and natural frequency of the system

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, power-engineering

If the G(S) is as follows:

[image]

Then how would you calculate the value of undamped natural frequency, damping factor, and quality factor of the system?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just consider the values of the denominator and from there I got the values of damping factor, quality factor and undamped natural frequency. (Ignoring the numerator all together)

Comment: If I break the terms as you suggested then how will I be able to find the values of damping, Quality and Natural frequency?

Answer (score 0):

The **TR-50** paper by R. P. Sallen & E. L. Key, dated 6 May 1954, and called "*A Practical Method of Designing RC Active Filters*" is still controlled by the US Air Force. It has been unclassified, but access to it still requires a formal request and a response. Despite the fact that an abridged version was published the next year, in 1955. What they write is very much worth the time to get and read.

At the outset, they start by setting the stage with \$a_i\$ and \$b_i\$ as real, positive constants, such that \$a_i\ge 0\$ and \$b_i\gt 0\$ and beginning with the following:

$$G_s = \frac{N_s}{D_s}=\frac{a_2s^2+a_1s+a_0}{b_2s^2+b_1s+b_0}$$

I asked you if you can apply algebra to transform the above abstract equation into something more meaningful. It's not rocket-science. Just algebra work. But the focus should be on the denominator, setting \$\omega_{_0}=\sqrt{\frac{b_0}{b_2}}\$ and \$2\zeta=\frac{b_1}{\sqrt{b_2 \,b_0}}\$. Then \$D_s=b_0\cdot\left[\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2+d\cdot\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)+1\right]\$. This is important.

\$\zeta=\frac1{2\,Q}\$ determines the **shape**. This is either an under-damped shape (\$\zeta\lt 1\$), a critically damped shape (\$\zeta= 1\$), or else an over-damped shape (\$\zeta\gt 1\$).

The critical frequency, \$\omega_{_0}\$, only determines the location (along the frequency axis) where a key part of the shape occurs.

These are the only two things that are important to understanding a 2nd order filter. The critical frequency and its shape. That's it. Nothing else matters.

Given any specific \$G_s\$, it may have a low-pass component, or a high-pass component, or a band-pass component. And/or any combination of these three. A filter that contains all of them will be called an **all-pass** filter. If it only has the low-pass component, then it is a low-pass filter. If it contains only the high-pass component, then it is a high pass filter. And if it contains only the band-pass component, then it is a band-pass filter. Anything that contains more than one of these will need context to determine what to call it. Keep these distinctions also in mind.

To re-cap, the **shape** is determined solely by \$\zeta\$ or \$Q\$, while \$\omega_0\$ determines the positions of the zeroes in the frequency domain.

The algebraic solution, one that elevates the denominator into key position because of the pole positions, is:

$$\begin{align*}
G_s&=\frac{a_2}{b_2}\frac{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2+2\zeta\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)+1}+\frac{a_1}{b_1}\frac{2\zeta\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)}{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2+2\zeta\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)+1}+\frac{a_0}{b_0}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2+2\zeta\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)+1}
\end{align*}$$

or,

$$\begin{align*}
G_s&=\frac{a_2}{b_2}\frac{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2+\frac1{Q}\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)+1}+\frac{a_1}{b_1}\frac{\frac1{Q}\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)}{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2+\frac1{Q}\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)+1}+\frac{a_0}{b_0}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)^2+\frac1{Q}\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)+1}
\end{align*}$$

*(Keep in mind that \$\zeta\$ and \$Q\$ each determine the other.)*

So, let's take your case where \$a_0=3.5\times 10^6\$, \$a_1=3.2\times 10^3\$, \$a_2=3.3\times 10^{-2}\$, \$b_0=3\times 10^7\$, \$b_1=1.42\times 10^3\$, and \$b_2=1\$.

From the above, find \$\omega_{_0}=\sqrt{\frac{3\times 10^7}{1}}\approx 5477.23\:\frac{\text{rad}}{\text{s}}\$ and \$\zeta=\frac12\frac{1.42\times 10^3}{\sqrt{1\,\cdot \,3\times 10^7}}\approx 0.1296\$. This is clearly under-damped.

We also find that the high-pass gain is \$\frac{a_2}{b_2}=\frac{3.3\times 10^{-2}}{1}=0.033\$, the band-pass gain is \$\frac{a_1}{b_1}=\frac{3.2\times 10^3}{1.42\times 10^3}\approx 2.254\$, and the low-pass gain is \$\frac{a_0}{b_0}=\frac{3.5\times 10^6}{3\times 10^7}\approx 0.1167\$. Clearly, the band-pass gain dominates here. But this is technically an all-pass filter, since it includes all three components.

That said above, you do have \$\zeta\approx 0.1296\$. So you know this is an under-damped filter response. (\$Q\approx 3.86\$.)

You can easily see the fact that this is under-damped from the following output from LTspice:

[image]

The peak frequency should be \$\frac{5477.23\:\frac{\text{rad}}{\text{s}}}{2\pi}\approx 871.73\:\text{Hz}\$.

LTspice finds something near this:

[image]

Close enough.

In short, the mathematics just works.

And I would strongly recommend that you read Sallen & Key's 1955 paper (or, if you can access it, their earlier TR-50 paper from 1954, which is much better in my opinion.)

Comment: thanks for the explanation but how will you know if this is resonant or not?

Comment: @JubeirAhmad What do you mean by "resonant?"

Comment: @JubeirAhmad You didn't define nor ask that in your original question.

Comment: Yeah I didn't but just wanted to know that the transfer function of the system is given and we have the values of Zeta, Q and Wn then how will we know if the system is resonant?

Comment: @JubeirAhmad Define your meaning. Provide references if that helps. If all you mean is the peak of the \$Q\$ then you have it, already. It's about \$f=871\:\text{Hz}\$. If you mean something else, then you need to tell me what exactly you mean when using the term/phrase.

Comment: Can we determine the resonance of the system by using the values of Quality factor, damping factor and the natural frequency?

Comment: @JubeirAhmad There are only three distinct parameters for each 2nd order component. These are 3 gain values (one for each of LP, BP, and HP), the critical frequency, and the damping factor. That's all there is. Nothing else remains. The meaning of "resonance frequency" is a matter of context. Likely, this is just the critical frequency. But there are only 3 gain values, one frequency value, and one damping factor. That's all that may exist for 2nd order. Nothing more can be said about it.